# New page not rendering | Cannot GET/

Tags: html, express

So I am trying to link out to my privacy policy from the footer through the following:

```
<a href="/privacypolicy"> Privacy Policy </a>
```

However, when the homepage is rendered on my local host, and I try to access the privacy policy (`privacypolicy.ejs`), I receive the error that

```
Cannot GET /privacypolicy
```

My privacy policy page is in a folder called views, and I am already serving this folder in my express server through:

```
app.set('views', join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Any thoughts on why I am not able to render the privacy policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up a handler to handle your request - `GET /privacypolicy`.

Do the same with what you did for `homepage`:

```
app.get('/privacypolicy', (req, res) => {
   res.render('privacypolicy');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made the page but not mentioned it in the express routes.

```
app.get("/privacypolicy",(req,res)=>{
   res.render(your_page);
   //render method renders the views folder pages
});
```